# Question about direct factors

Tags: abstract-algebra

this is a problem from hungerford:

"A normal subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be a direct factor if there exists a (normal) subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G = H \times K$.

1. if $H$ is a direct factor of $K$ and $K$ is a direct factor of $G$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.
2. If $H$ is a direct factor of $G$, then every homomorphism $H \to G$ may be extended to an endomorphism $G \to G$. However, a monomorphism $H \to G$ need not be extendible to an automorphism $G \to G$"

I have a few questions:
1) why is the normality of $K$ put in brackets? Is there something that suggests that $K$ must be normal if it exists?

2) how would I go about proving these? For the first one, I know that $G = K \times L$ for some $L$ normal in $G$ and I know $K = H \times J$ for some $J$ normal in $K$.

So I can conclude $G = H \times J \times L$ but I don't see how to conclude normality of $H$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\times$ do you mean the group operation or cartesian product, because if you mean the latter you should use $\approx$, not $=$.

Comment: Do you mean $G = H \oplus K$ ?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: It’s the Cartesian product, and the OP is quoting: by that point in the book Hungerford has already noted that he won’t bother with the distinction between internal and external direct products unless it actually matters.

Comment: I think $G \times H$ is the standard notation for direct product. If you write $G \oplus H$, that indicates that the groups are abelian. Equality here does actually mean isomorphism, but that is not uncommon in algebra, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $K$ must be normal if it exists: if $G=H\times K$, the projection map from $G$ to $H$ is a homomorphism with kernel $K$. You can use this idea to finish answering the first question. For the first part of the second question, note that if $f:H\to H\times K$ and $g:K\to H\times K$ are homomorphisms, then the map $H\times K\to H\times K:\langle h,k\rangle\mapsto\langle f(h),g(k)\rangle$ is an endomorphism. For the second part, consider the group $G=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: @user103461: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sir, could you please elaborate how the example, you gave for second part is working?

Comment: @akansha: The map $\langle n,0\rangle\mapsto\langle 2n,2n\rangle$ is a monomorphism from $\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$ to $G$ that can’t be extended to an automorphism of $G$: if $f$ is an endomorphism of $G$ extending this map, and $f(\langle k,\ell\rangle)=\langle 1,1\rangle$, then $f(\langle 2k,2\ell\rangle)=\langle 2,2\rangle=f(\langle 1,0\rangle)$, so $f$ is not an automorphism.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : For the first part of the second question, $f(h)$ is a $2$-tuple, so is $g(h)$, so the result seems to be a combination of $2$-tuples to me, where do I get wrong? I mean, H becomes a cross product of two sets, so does K.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding just the question of why a direct factor is normal, note that it suffices to check that $K$ is a normal subgroup of the direct product $H \times K$.  Brian Scott in his answer indicated how to see this by regarding $K$ as the kernel of the projection onto the first factor.

I just wanted to point out that one can also see this directly:  if $(h,k) \in H \times K$ and $(1,k')$ is an element of $K$ (identified with $1 \times K$, of course), then $$(h,k) (1,k') (h,k)^{-1} = (h,k) (1,k')(h^{-1},k^{-1}) = (1, k k' k^{-1})$$ again lies  in $K$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Let $H \times K \approx G$, where $K \trianglelefteq G$, then projection onto $K$ has kernel $H\times \{1\} \approx H$.  So $H$ is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $G$.  Chaining together $H, K, G$, we have that $H$ is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $K$ which is isomorphic to normal subgroup of $G$.

Let $H$ be a direct factor of $G$.  Let $f : H \to G$ be a homomorphism, and define $f : H \times K \to G$ to be $h \times k \mapsto f(h) + 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hungerford uses $H\times K$ to denote the internal direct product of H and K, so by definition, K is normal